# Email attachment name not decoding on outlook by java mail?

Tags: java, utf-8, jakarta-mail

I have sent mail by application through java mail api with attachment file using UTF-8 (Общи правила по безопасност на труда при транспортиране.pdf) to outlook mail . 
But i received email with different email attachment name (=UTF-8B0J7QsdGJ0Lgg0LRgNCw0LLQuNCw....).

Its not reproducible on gmail smtp server .

I have tried with CP866 its working but it create problem for Japanese and chinese language attachment name.

```
public static MimeBodyPart createMimeBodyPart (File attachFile)
{
    FileDataSource attachDataSource = new FileDataSource(attachFile.getPath());
    MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(attachDataSource));
    String filename = attachFile.getName();
    mbp.setHeader("Content-type", "application/pdf charset=utf-8");
    mbp.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(filename, "UTF-8", "B"));
    mbp.setHeader("Content-transfer-encoding", "base64");
    return mbp;
}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve]

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I have attached image file .

Comment: @Amessihel I have copied code with attachment of image

Comment: This [JavaMail FAQ entry](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#encodefilename) might help.

Comment: when i encoded attachment name it encoded partially ,  not complete string .